# Mockito verify OptionalDouble

Tags: java, mockito, hamcrest

I have a method that is being called with an `OptionalDouble` as the input type, I want to verify that it was called with the right value. However I can't check for an exact match due to rounding errors etc.

For a normal double I'm using this:

```
  verify(observer, times(1)).accept(doubleThat(closeTo(x * (1 - y) / z, 0.00000001)));
```

But I can't work out any simple way to do the same for `OptionalDouble`. Do I need to write my own handler here?

If I did need a new handler can anyone point me to an example I can build from?

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use ArgumentCaptor I believe. eg below

```
final ArgumentCaptor<OptionalDouble> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(OptionalDouble.class);

    ........
    .............
    verify(observer).accept(captor.capture());

    assertEquals(expected.getAsDouble(), captor.getValue().getAsDouble(), delta);
```

Comment: Does AdditionalMatchers.eq support OptionalDouble?

Comment: it doesn't , `ArgumentCaptor` is another option

Comment: Yeah, that looks like it should work - it would be better not to need 2 steps but maybe there's no choice here. Thanks.